# Viewholder onClickListener reference the wrong view in android

Tags: java, android, share, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerView which loads images from firebase using picasso.Each item(image) have a shareButton underneath it which when clicked converts the view into bitmap and uses share intent to share it with other apps.*The problem is it shares the next image(item) not the image under which the shareButton was placed.*
**Here is the code for bitmap conversion and share-**

```
// Can be triggered by a view event such as a button press
public void onShareItem(View v) {
    // Get access to bitmap image from view
    ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
    // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(ivImage);
    if (bmpUri != null) {
        // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");

        // Launch sharing dialog for image
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));

    } else {

    }
}

// Returns the URI path to the Bitmap displayed in specified ImageView
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

**How the share button is setup-**

```
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());

            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());


            viewHolder.mShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    onShareItem(view);



                }
            });


        }
    };

    mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}

public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    Button mShareButton;


    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mShareButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
    }
```

**This is how I am adding data**

```
 public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    Button mShareButton;


    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mShareButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setImage(final Context ctx, final String image) {


        final ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);


        Picasso.with(ctx)
                .load(image)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .into(post_image, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(ctx)
                                .load(image)
                                .error(R.drawable.header)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                                .into(post_image);
                    }


                });


    }


}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing `ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.post_image);` instead of `ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) v;` in the `onShareItem` method.

Comment: @Titus I tried it but got the following error when I click the share button. java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Comment: Oh, now I see that you're passing the `Button` to the `onShareItem` method, you'll need to pass it the `ImageView` instead.

Comment: Sorry I am really new to android,didn't understood what you wrote.Can you tell me with code?I would really appreciate that sir. @Titus

Comment: @Titus I found the real problem and changed the title of the question,this may help you to understand the question easily.

Comment: Post your onBindViewHolder method

Comment: @ScottCooper I updated my question,there is no method named onBindViewHolder.The updated question shows how I am binding data.Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @RohanSuri are you not using a RecyclerView? What method calls populateViewHolder?

Comment: @ScottCooper Actually I am using firebase as my database,when I tried to find the usage of populateViewHolder,I found that it is used in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java.This class is a generic way of backing an RecyclerView with a Firebase location.
It handles all of the child events at the given Firebase location. It marshals received data into the given
 class type.It is also having the onBindViewHolder.

Comment: @rohanSuri Ok one last question, what does modal.getImage() return, is it a String/Uri?

Comment: @ScottCooper Yes the image here is passed as a String.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the image itself to the share method?

```
protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
            viewHolder.mShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onShareItem(model.getImage());
                }
            });
        }
```

Then share the image uri directly.

```
// Can be triggered by a view event such as a button press
public void onShareItem(String image) {
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(image);

        // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");

        // Launch sharing dialog for image
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
}
```

Comment: This didn't worked "File format not supported" error in every app.I guess we have to convert the image to bitmap first.Now I am literally tired of this bug.@Scott